# ASP.NET 5 Beta 7 (Web Tools 2015 Beta7) - wwwroot/index.html not served

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, static-files

I'm trying to setup a new web application and I would to load the index.html (wwwroot folder) at startup.

In ASP.NET 5 Beta 6 this can be simply done only with *app.UseStaticFiles()* call inside Configure method even if MVC is configured.

Now, in Beta 7 (with Web Tools 2015 Beta7 installed), this doesn't work anymore :(
I found on many articles that I'm supposed to add this call too:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    DefaultFileNames = new [] { "index.html" }
});
```

But even with that the index.html is not served by the framework.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // Add static files to the request pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Add default files to the request pipeline
        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
        {
            DefaultFileNames = new [] { "index.html" }
        });

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Someone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I suspect that it worked before because IIS fall through was opted in by default, but now you have to opt in explicitly  https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/54

Comment: Thanks! The problem is exactly that! With app.RunIISPipeline() all works as before

Comment: I have promoted my comment to an answer, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked before because IIS fall through was opted in by default, but now you have to opt in explicitly [as mentioned in the breaking changes in the announcements repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/54)